# When every open cover admits a $\sigma$-disjoint subcover?

Tags: gn.general-topology

We say that a sequence $(\mathcal X_n)$ of families of subsets of a topological space $X$ is a $\sigma$-disjoint cover of $X$ if every family $\mathcal X_n$ consists of mutually disjoint sets and $\bigcup\limits_n\bigcup\mathcal X_n=X$.

Let us say that a space $X$ is weakly Lindelof, if every open cover of $X$ admits a $\sigma$-disjoint subcover. Clearly, every Lindelof space is weakly Lindelof.

**Question 1.** Is there any well-known in the literature name for the class of "weakly Lindelof" spaces?

The following question concerns weaker property than "weak Lindeloffness".

**Question 2.** Does there exist a $\sigma$-disjoint cover of a Banach space $X$ by open balls of diameters $\le 1$?

Comment: I don’t know how the property you describe is called, but I’d say *weakly Lindelof* is already taken: any open cover of X contains a countable cover of a dense subset of X.

Answer (score 3):

**comment**
I found  [HERE](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Paracompact_space)

> A space is called *screened* if every open covering has a $\sigma$-disjoint open refinement

Do you think this is equivalent to weakly Lindelof: every open covering has a $\sigma$-disjoint subcover ?

That page refers to
D.K. Burke, "Covering properties" K. Kunen (ed.) J.E. Vaughan (ed.) , *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology* , North-Holland (1984) Chapt. 9; pp. 347–422

**added**
Screened is not equivalent to weakly Lindelof.  An uncountable discrete space is screened: indeed every open cover has a disjoint open refinement consisting of singletons.  But not every open cover has a sigma-disjoint subcover.
Let $X$ be our uncountable set.  Choose one distinguished point $x_0$.  Let us consider the open cover $\mathcal U := \{\;\{x_0,x\}\;: x \in X \setminus \{x_0\}\}$ made up of doubletons.  A disjoint subfamliy of $\mathcal U$ can only have one set in it, so a sigma-disjoint subfamily of $\mathcal U$ can be at most countable.